# Not able to run node project in docker on windows

Tags: docker

I want to run my node project inside docker. I am getting this error while building the app from docker

```
error during connect: Post http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.40/build?buildargs=%7B%7D&cachefrom=%5B%5D&cgroupparent=&cpuperiod=0&cpuquota=0&cpusetcpus=&cpusetmems=&cpushares==0&cpusetcpus=&cpusetmems=&cpushares=0&dockerfile=Dockerfile&labels=%7B%7D&memory=0&memswap=0&networkmode=default&rm=1&session=vgi82r9lm7xo2khvpnget=&ulimits=null&version=1: open
 //.moghe8i&shmsize=0&t=project-node&target=&ulimits=null&version=1: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the dvated to connect. This error may alsoefault daemon configuration on 
Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect.
This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.
```

Following is the docker file

```
FROM node:latest
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

All the project-related files are present inside same folder

I am new to docker can anyone help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

**Issue**

> If the Docker daemon fails to start up with Windows, or stops for some
>   reason, you can get network connection errors or warnings regarding
>   the Docker daemon service when you try to run any commands:

```
the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.
```

**Prerequisites**

Before performing these steps, you must meet the following requirements:

- Windows 10
- Docker for Windows

**Resolution**

> When the Docker daemon fails to start on Windows, or stops
>   unexpectedly during normal operations, you'll get a network connection
>   error regarding the Docker daemon letting you know that it is
>   unreachable. The Docker daemon is also commonly referred to as the
>   Docker for Windows service. Usually, restarting the service will
>   resolve the error.

Option 1:

- Restart the Docker for Windows service through the Windows GUI by right clicking the service and choosing restart (or right click, stop, right click, start):

[image]

Option 2:

```
Net stop com.docker.service
Net start com.docker.service
```

[docker-for-windows-fails-with-a-daemon-not-running-message](https://success.docker.com/article/docker-for-windows-fails-with-a-daemon-not-running-message)